# Phase fluctuations electromagnetic field

Tags: statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes

The electric field strength is given by:

$$E(t)=E_0 \exp(i(\omega t + \phi(t))),$$

where $\phi(t)=\sqrt{2D} \ \Gamma(t)$.

$D$ is the diffusion constant and $\Gamma(t)$ the line width. We have to assume this obeys a Wiener process so that the phases are delta-correlated in time.

I have to proof that the following holds:

$$\langle \exp[i(\phi(t_1)-\phi(t_2))] \rangle=\exp(-D|t_1-t_2|).$$

I tried the following:

$$\langle \exp[i(\phi(t_1)-\phi(t_2))] \rangle = \frac{1}{T}\int^{T}_{0} \exp(i(\phi(t_1)-\phi(t_2)))dt,$$

but I do not understand what is meant with the time average in this case. This clearly does not give the right solution since $t_1,t_2$ are arbitrary fixed times. Could somebody give me a hint how to go further with this problem?

Comment: How about average over the noise instead of time average?

Comment: What do mean with averaging over noise? The phases ?

Comment: Suppose we want to take an ensemble average of $f(X)$, we have $\langle f(X) \rangle = \int f(x) p(x) \; dx$ where $p(x)$ is the probability density of random variable $X$. But I am not sure if time average equals to ensemble average in your case.

Comment: Still I do not understand what you mean, since the probability density is not defined here. Yes, I think we may assume an ergodic system.

Comment: I think you know the distribution since $\Gamma(t)$ is a Wiener process, and its exponential is Geometric Brownian motion.